# How do I redisplay the same dropdown list with the previous selection instead of the default selection?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have two dropdown lists. If the user only selects something from one selection box, I want to re-render the page where it has the same dropdown lists, except the one that was selected shows the previous selection instead of the default selection.

the html looks like

```
<div>
<select name = "menu" value = "{{menu}}">
    <option value = "selected">select something</option>
    <option value = "a">a</option>
    <option value = "b">b</option>
    <option value = "c">c</option>
</select>
</div>

<div>
<select name = "location" value = "{{location}}">
    <option value = "selected">select something</option>
    <option value = "d">d</option>
    <option value = "e">e</option>
    <option value = "f">f</option>
</select>
</div>
```

the python looks like
menu = self.request.get('menu')
        location = self.request.get('location')

```
    if menu!="selected" and location!="selected":
        d = Delivery(parent = delivery_key(),
                 menu = menu, location = location)
        d.put()
        deliverystatus = "success"
        self.render('page.html',
                     deliverystatus = deliverystatus, menu = menu, location = location)
    else:
       error = "please select something from both lists"
       self.render("page.html",
                   menu = menu, location = location, error = error)
```

When there is an error and I rerender the page I get "select something" as the default in both boxes. How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML form, add a conditional that `if menu_value==this_option_value` print `selected` in the option. So something like this:

```
<select name = "menu" value = "{{menu}}">
    <option value = "selected">select something</option>
    <option value = "a" <% if menu == 'a': %>selected<% end> >a</option>
    <option value = "b" <% if menu == 'b': %>selected<% end> >b</option>
    <option value = "c" <% if menu == 'c': %>selected<% end> >c</option>
</select>
```

You should check the syntax but that should give you the idea of how to do it.

Comment: does anyone know what the syntax is supposed to be? i added python if/else statements to each option specifying when the option value should be the default "selected" but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does the variable `menu` still return the value `selected`?

Comment: yes, the dropdown still automatically displays "select something" even if "a" was selected. i added python for each option saying if menu returns "a", then replace the option value = "selected" tag for "select something" with just option and make the default selection "a". (though this doesn't work, would a more efficient solution be to loop thru the selections and, if menu matches the option value, reset that option to the default display?)